# Need to use Buddhist year (2562) instead of Gregorian year (1992) in React-native

Tags: react-native

***Hi everyone.***

How we can custom **DatePickerIOS** and **DatePickerAndroid** to use **Buddhist year** (2562) instead of **Gregorian year** (1992) without care about config default calendar type in OS setting ?

Comment: Wouldn't you just add 544 (or 543, depending on the source) to the year you wanna display?

Comment: @VilleKoo yes, but not at all. if your current os is select on buddhist year it will show [ Months ] [ Days ] [ Years with postfix BE ] you can not add or remove 543 directly. it will show [ Months ] [ Days ] [ (2562 - 543) = 1992 BE ]